# How to access a dictionary inside a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
names = [x for x in cal if x['full_county_name'] != None]
for name in names:
    cities = name['name'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    counties = name['full_county_name'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    latitude = name['primary_latitude'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    longitude = name['primary_longitude'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    info = {'name': cities,'county': counties,'latitude': latitude,'longitude': longitude}
    return info
```

There's the code. I'm getting information from a json, filtering out data I don't need in a list comprehension, and then in the for loop building the desired dictionary. The return statement works INSIDE the loop, but how do I get the dictionary I need OUTSIDE the loop.

Once I can access the dictionary info inside the for loop, I can proceed to the rest of my code. The best I've gotten is a `NoneType`, the first value of the dictionary, or the last value of the dictionary. Would anyone have any pointers or is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: Your code is worthless to us because we can't paste it into our interpreters to check its behavior. Please give us a minimal example and the expected output / result that we can actually comprehend without knowing the rest of your code. In particular, it is obscure to me what the code you provided has to do with the more general question in the title.

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Comment: You're returning *inside* your loop, hence it will only "loop" once. I doubt that's your intention.

Comment: What dictionary? What's not working with the code you show in your question (be specific)? If there's an error message, show it. What's the input and the output would you like? Suggest you read and follow [**_How do I ask a good question?_**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're trying to accumulate all the dicts from the for-loop.  In that case, eliminate the *return* which terminates the loop and replace it with a `results.append(info)` which will accumulate the dicts in a list:

```
results = []
names = [x for x in cal if x['full_county_name'] != None]
for name in names:
    cities = name['name'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    counties = name['full_county_name'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    latitude = name['primary_latitude'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    longitude = name['primary_longitude'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    info = {'name': cities,'county': counties,'latitude': latitude,'longitude': longitude}
    results.append(info)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Wish I thought of this earlier!